# Calculating combined risk

Tags: absolute-risk

Let's assume that there are only three types of disease; A, B and C. If a lifetime risk to get disease A is 5%, risk for B is 5% and risk for C is 10%, and a same person can get more than one disease, how do we calculate the total lifetime risk to getting affected by any disease for a single person?

Comment: Check [addition rule in probability](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/addition-rule-of-probability).

Comment: A wide range of valid answers are consistent with this question, because it does not contain enough information for a definite answer.  For instance, what if $B$ is a sequel of $A$ (that is, you only get $B$ after you get $A$)?  A little thought about the possibilities will reveal that *any* answer between 10% (the largest probability) and 20% (their sum, which does not exceed 100%) is plausible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the three deseaes are independent, you can multiply the chances of not getting each together, resulting in the chance of getting none. This means, $1 -0.9*0.95*0.95$ is the result you are looking for (about 19%)

Why does this work? Well. 5% of people get disease A, so we are left with 95% of people (we don't care if the other 5% have dieseases B and/or C as well) Now, 95% of that 95% have neither A nor B, and so on....